# how to return DB (database/sql) type in golang?

Tags: postgresql, go

I use Go with PostgreSQL using [github.com/lib/pq](http://github.com/lib/pq).

I want to call this `opendb()` function in other functions but I'm having problem with the return value.

```
 package database

    import (
            "fmt"
            "database/sql"
            _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    )

    const (
            host = "localhost"
            port = 5432
            user = "postgres"
            password = "pgpassword"
            dbname = "postgres"
    )

    func opendb() (*DB) {
            psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s " +
              "sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, dbname)

            db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)

            if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
            }

            defer db.Close()

            return db
    }
```

If you run this:

```
$ go run main.go
```

It will show this error:

```
error:

    undefined: DB
```

Comment: you need to point from where type `DB` is imported. In your case it will be `*sql.DB`

Comment: Do not do `defer db.Close()` inside `func opendb`. It will be executed right after return, and you will get a closed connection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the return datatype should be `*sql.DB` 
changing
`func opendb() (*DB) {`

to

`func opendb() (*sql.DB) {`

should work